# AADSTS50011 - The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm getting this error while trying to use OpenID to login from my mobile app.

I'm using React Native App Auth (https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth#azure-active-directory) to authenticate my app to AAD. The same setup is already working with Okta and Google OpenID providers.

These are the settings I'm using on the app:

```
{
  issuer: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{directory_id}/v2.0',
  clientId: {my_client_id},
  redirectUrl: 'com.krev.krev://oauth2redirect',
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email']
}
```

and this is the relevant info in the app manifest on AAD:

```
"replyUrlsWithType": [
    {
        "url": "com.krev.krev://oauth2redirect",
        "type": "InstalledClient"
    }
],
```

I already tried changing "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching" to no avail

Comment: Are you 100% sure that is *exactly* what is in the app settings? No typos or missing characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice several of the `redirectUrl` examples in https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth use the pattern `<scheme>:/<something>` (with only one forward slash `/`), but in the settings you shared, you have `<scheme>://<something>` (with two forward slashes `//`). You may have accidentally left only one slash and authorized two slashes (or vice versa), or had another typo.

Comment: Sadly, no, they're the same url, copied/pasted already several times. The double slash is a requirement of AAD, elsewhere I'm using a single slash. But it's set the same in the app and in the AAD manifest

Answer (score 2):

Not really relevant, but it was an error on my side. I was overriding the url in another place in the code.